# "the file name must end with .xml" error for jpg file in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, file-extension

I am getting this error while building my app. The drawable folder has the valid .jpg file and this is causing the error. How to bypass this? Also, I noticed that the path shown in the error is "main\res\routine\Routine.jpg", but there is no such folder in the project.

````
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"The file name must end with .xml",
"sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\AndroidStudioProjects\\project3\\app\\src\\main\\res\\routine\\Routine.JPG"}],
"tool":"Resource and asset merger"}```
UPDATE: solved the problem by reuploading the pic and saving it in drawable_V21. still dont know about that error message though. might be a bug
````

Comment: "but there is no such folder in the project" -- the build tools disagree with you.

Comment: @CommonsWare there really is not. cant add picture here. i would know if there is any folder like that in my project before posting here, wouldn't i?

Comment: "cant add picture here" -- you could upload images elsewhere and link to them. "i would know if there is any folder like that in my project before posting here, wouldn't i?" -- again, the build tools think that there is a `routines/` directory in your `res/` directory in this module. So, we need to determine why the build tools think that `routines/` exists while you do not. How are you looking for `routines/`? Are you using Android Studio? If so, does the drop-down over the project tree say "Android" or "Project"? If it says "Android", change it to "Project", then look again for `routines/`.

Comment: I guess that error you're experiencing is because of the file extension being in .JPG instead of .jpg try changing it. It may help somehow.

Comment: thanks, solved the problem by reuploading the pic and saving it in the drawable_v21 folder instead. dont know about that routine folder error message though

Comment: @CodeREDInnovations please add your comment as answer so that can be accepted

Answer (score 0):

I guess that error you're experiencing is because of the file extension being in .JPG instead of .jpg try changing it. It may help somehow